# msbuild empty property value is threated as null value

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-task

I have a task configuration property `RelativePathOverride` defined like this:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <RelativePathOverride>..\..\</RelativePathOverride>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

and then used as

```
  <Target Name="CustomTaskTarget" AfterTargets="PostBuildEvent">
    <SimpleTask RelativePathOverride="$(RelativePathOverride)"/> 
  </Target>
```

The task code is following:

```
public class SimpleTask : Task
{
    public string RelativePathOverride { get; set; }
    

    public override bool Execute()
    {
        Log.LogMessage(MessageImportance.High, $"RelativePathOverride: {RelativePathOverride ?? "NULL"}");

        if (RelativePathOverride == null)
        {
            // default value
            RelativePathOverride = "..\\";
        }

    }
}
```

This works fine. However, the problem is that when I provide the empty value for the `RelativePathOverride` property then it's defaulted to `NULL`!

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <RelativePathOverride></RelativePathOverride>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

In my logic - I want the empty value to be an empty value! This is very important because we are talking about a relative path. `NULL` value means that there is NO override provided, so the default will be hardcoded to `..\`. But since empty property value is also threated as `null` then this corrupts my logic..

Is there is native approach to allow passing empty values into property?

p.s. on a side note (might be related) - 1 space is also threated as `null`..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most instances, comparisons in msbuilds usually interpret "empty" and null as the same thing. I suggest using `.\` or `.` in your case.

Comment: the behavior is by design and nobody is going to fix it because it will then be a breaking change.. MS does not want to take responsibility for this. The "issue" could be closed. For anyone interested - try using workarounds..